# Unable to enter function absurd result

Tags: c

```
int fun(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) 
    {
        fun(n-1);
    
        printf("%d ", n);
    
        fun(n-1);  
    }
    else
        return n; 
}
```

When I enter `(n=4)` I get `( 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 )`.

So I don't understand: How it does this? Can someone please explain me this step by step?

Comment: In general if you need a step by step of what a function does, you can use a debugger.

Comment: You can't change the existing question entirely. This invalidates the answers. If you have a new question, you should ask in a new thread, however please note that what you are asking is off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all note that you only return a value if n is 0 or negative, so if you call fun with an argument greater than zero and then try to use the return value, you're invoking undefined behaviour. You should either have a return statement in both branches of the if or remove the return statement and change the return type of the function to void.

As for why the function prints what it prints, let's approach this step-by-step by working upwards from the base case:

What happens if you call fun with 0 as the argument (or a negative number)? The if condition is false and it goes directly to the return statement - nothing is printed. So fun(0); prints nothing. Okay.

Now what happens for fun(1)? This time the if condition is true, so the body is executed. The body consists of three function calls involving n. Since n is 1 (and thus n-1 is 0), we get: fun(0);, printf("%d ", 1); and again fun(0);. As we've established in the previous paragraph, fun(0); prints nothing, so all that happens is that "1 " is printed.

Now what happens for fun(2)? Again the if condition is true, so the body is executed. The body consists of three function calls involving n. Since n is 2 (and thus n-1 is 1), we get: fun(1);, printf("%d ", 2); and again fun(1);. As we've established in the previous paragraph, fun(1); prints "1 ", so this will print "1 ", followed by "2 ", followed by "1 " again, making the final output of f(2) "1 2 1 ".

Now if you continue this approach for fun(3) and fun(4), you'll come up with the same output for fun(4) as the one you posted.